# How to solve java.lang.IllegalStateException: server in wrong state Exception

Tags: java, rest, exception, jersey, httpserver

I am trying to deploy restful web-service in core java project (swing application). I am using jersy for that.
I have searched to many site in google but i can't found why this append.

```
public class Main { 
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{        
    ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class);
    URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(10049).build();

    HttpServer server = JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri,resourceConfig);
    server.start();
    System.out.println("Press Enter to stop the server. ");
    System.in.read();
    server.stop(0);
}
}


@Path("/hello")
public class MyResource {

// This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
}

// This method is called if XML is request
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "sdasd";
}

// This method is called if HTML is request
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "dsdfd";
}
}
```

Exception :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: server in wrong state
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:139)
at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.start(HttpServerImpl.java:58)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory$2.start(JdkHttpServerFactory.java:363)
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

How to resolve above exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue is resolved by removing line **server.start();**

Line **JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri,resourceConfig);** is creating http server as well as start server.

"server in wrong state Exception" comes when you are trying to start server again.